# Stacking Sensei's Divining Top Abilities

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I believe it is possible, but I am asking for confirmation:
Can you activate [Sensei's Divining Top](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=sensei%27s%20divining%20top)'s first ability, and then, in response, activate the second ability, allowing you to draw a card, put SDT on top of your library, and then look at the top three cards on your library and put them back in any order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do exactly what you describe. You can activate Top's first ability, then, while that ability is on the stack, activate its second ability. Then the second ability will resolve, and you will draw a card, then put Top on top of your library. Finally, the first ability will resolve, and you will look at and reorder the top three cards of your library, including the Top you just put there.